# Optimizing a Difference in Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have the following expressions:

> $$ \frac{1}{2} \Bigg [1 + \sqrt{a^2 + (b e^{-\gamma(\tau)})^2 + (c e^{-\gamma(\tau)})^2} \Bigg ]; $$

```
f1=1/2 (1 + Sqrt[
    a^2 + (b Exp[-γ (\[tau)])^2 + (c Exp[-γ (\[tau)])^2])
```

and

> $$ \frac{1}{2} \Bigg [1 + a^2 + e^{-\gamma(t)}(b^2 + c^2) \Bigg ]. $$

```
f2=1/2 (1 + a^2 + Exp[-γ (\[tau)] (b^2 + c^2))
```

I have already found these expressions such that **for all** values of $a, b$ and $c$ such that

> $$ a, b, c \in [0, 1] \quad \text{such that} \quad |a|^2 + |b|^2 + |c|^2 = 1, $$

the first expression will always yield a higher value for all times, $\tau$.

Now, I am interested in figuring out **certain values** of $a, b$ and $c$ **meeting the aforementioned condition** for which the difference between the first and the second expressions is the largest. I have tried working with some sample numbers based on qualitative reasons.

Is there a specific method to go about doing this in *Mathematica.* Also, the difference will be different at different times due to the exponential term, which I'll get by running a numerical integration.

I'm not quite sure how to tackle this problem in *Mathematica,* if there's a specific method for it.

**Edit:**

Note that the values of the parameters (to follow) and the expression for gamma is given by the code:

```
G = 0.1;
\[Omega]c = 10;
\[Beta] = 1;

integralgamma[\[Omega]_, \[Tau]_] := 
4 G \[Omega] Exp[-\[Omega]/\[Omega]c] ((1 - 
   Cos[\[Omega] \[Tau]])/\[Omega]^(2)) Coth[\[Beta] \[Omega]/2];
```

I would run a numerical integration over omega first and then plot the graph with respect to tau, which is the time. The domain for the time is technically $(0, \infty)$ but for almost all cases, the curves of both expressions level off when tau (time) is in the range 10-20 seconds.

**P.S:** The centered LaTeX-ed expressions aren't written in Mathematica code. Read them as mathematical expressions.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Diogo I haven't run a code to get something on this end thus far. I actually don't know how to approach the problem.

Comment: Would anyone have any idea?

Comment: Are you sure there are values for `a`,`b`, and `c` for which the entire function `Abs[f2-f1](gamma,t)` is greater than for any other values?

Comment: @Feyre That's the problem which I have hinted/mentioned in the question as well. Since there's a time dependent exponential factor, the difference will be different/dynamical at each point. So I don't know if there's such a pair of values. I want to get as close as to making the difference as large as possible. The curves are well behaved for all cases; they decrease and then they eventually level off. I just don't know if there's a specific method to go about it other than playing around with such combinations of the said variables.

Comment: So, you want the integral of `Abs[f2-f1]` to be as large as possible? For which domain?

Comment: @Feyre I think you can drop the absolute value function since f_2 is always greater than or equal to f_1. The domain is a, b, c between 0 and 1 and the condition mentioned in the question. Wait, let me edit the question.

Comment: I meant, the domain for `t,gamma`

Comment: @Feyre Wait, let me include the expression for gamma as well.

Comment: @Feyre Done; edited.

Comment: Is $\gamma$ a function or a multiplier of $t$?

Comment: @Szabolcs $\gamma$ is a function of $\tau$, the elapsed time. I have edited the proof to remove the notational inconsistency between $t$ and $\tau$.

Comment: Your Mathematica notation is incorrect then. `a(b)` means `a` times `b` in Mathematica.

Comment: @Szabolcs I didn't mean to write the centered LaTeX-ed expressions in Mathematica code.

Answer (score 2):

Let us simplify your formulas manually first.

Let us denote $e^{-\gamma(t)}$ by `e`, and $a^2, b^2, c^2$ by `a2`, `b2`, `c2`.

Then

```
f1 = 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[a2 + b2 e^2 + c2 e^2]);

f2 = 1/2 (1 + a2 + e (b2 + c2));
```

You want to maximize `f1 - f2` with the constraints $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ and $a,b,c \in [0,1]$.  From your notation, I also assume that $0 < e^{-\gamma(t)} < 1$.

```
result = Maximize[
  {f1 - f2, a2 + b2 + c2 == 1 && 0 < e < 1},
  {a2, b2, c2}
  ]

Refine[result, 0 < e < 1]

{(1 - 2 e + e^2)/(8 (1 + e)), 
 {a2 -> (1 + 3 e)/(4 (1 + e)), b2 -> 0, c2 -> (3 + e)/(4 (1 + e))}}
```

While I didn't give the constraints that $a,b,c \in [0,1]$, we can see that the result satisfies this.

---

If we use the method of Lagrange multipliers, and do the calculations with Mathematica, it turns out that the following is a solution for any `0 <= b2 <= 1/2`:

```
{a2 -> (1 + 3 e)/(4 + 4 e), c2 -> (3 + e - 4 b2 (1 + e))/(4 (1 + e))}
```

Comment: What about the issue in $e^{- \gamma (\tau)}, \gamma(\tau)$ has to be numerically integrated first?

Comment: @JunaidAftab I don't understand what you are asking.  Perhaps you should make the question clearer, in addition to fixing the Mathematica notation. I showed how to maximize for a,b,c, treating the exponential term as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If you introduce a spherical coordinates parametrization

$a=\sin(q)$,
$b=\cos(q)\cos(\phi)$,
$c=\cos(q)\sin(\phi)$,

you can write your problem in much simpler terms:

```
f1 = 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[Sin[q]^2 + k^2 Cos[q]^2])
f2 = 1/2 (1 + Sin[q]^2 + k Cos[q]^2)
```

where $k=\exp(\gamma(t))$

Now for a given value of $k=\exp(\gamma(t))$ you can do the 1d numerical maximization:

```
NMaximize[f1 - f2 /. {k -> 1}, {q}]
(*{0., {q -> -6.96782}}*)
```

Notice, $f1-f2$ do not depend on $b$ and $c$ in an independent fashion. They always enter in $b^2+c^2\equiv\cos^2(q)$ combination.

Then running

```
n = NMaximize[(f1 - f2) /. {k -> 1}, {q}][[2]]
o = FindInstance[((Cos[q] Cos[\[Phi]])^2 + (Cos[q] Sin[\[Phi]])^2 + 
      Sin[q]^2 == 1 && 0 < Cos[q] Cos[\[Phi]] < 1 && 
    0 < Cos[q] Sin[\[Phi]] < 1) /. n, \[Phi], Reals][[1]]
```

> {ϕ -> -83.9}

Giving us

```
{a, b, c} = {Sin[q], Cos[q] Cos[\[Phi]], Cos[q] Sin[\[Phi]]} /. n /. o
```

> {0.58074, 0.491245, 0.649168}

Comment: Do you mean `NMaximize[(f2 - f1) /. {k -> 1}, {q}][[2]]`?
But how do you get `b` and `c` from this expression, when you have no `phi`?

Comment: What about $\phi$?

Comment: @Feyre that's the point. It is irrelevant. `b`and `c`are not independent here. They enter in a combination $b^2+c^2=\cos^2(q)$

Comment: Do you agree with what I've added?

Comment: @JunaidAftab How about now? This gives us three real values. {check the edit I'm proposing}

Comment: @Feyre Can you explaint he syntax/meaning of the commands involving n and o? I get the command with the n. I'm not sure what's the role of the command with the o. Should you be putting the constraints, that appear in the FindInstance command, in the NMaximize command?

Comment: Following $a=\sin(q),b=\cos(q)\cos(\phi),c=\cos(q)\sin(\phi)$, This is where I calculated a numerical value for `phi`. The constraints cannot be in the `NMaximize[]` as it disregards `phi`.

Comment: @Feyre I still don't get the use of the command FindInstance. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @Feyre When I run: `n = NMaximize[(f1 - f2) /. {k -> 1}, {\[Theta]}][[2]]` and `o = o = FindInstance[((Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]])^2 + (Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\
\[Phi]])^2 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2 == 1 && 
      0 < Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]] < 1 && 
      0 < Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]] < 1) /. n, \[Theta], Reals][[1]]` I get the errors `NMaximize::nnum: The function value -1.+1/2 (1.4564 +Sin[q]^2) is not a number at {\[Theta]} = {-0.829053}. >>` and `ReplaceAll::reps: {\[Theta]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>`

Comment: @Feyre and `FindInstance::naqs: Cos[\[Theta]]^2+Cos[\[Phi]]^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2+Sin[\[Theta]]^2 Sin[\[Phi]]^2==1&&0<Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]]<1&&0<Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]]<1/. {\[Theta]} is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities. >>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42573/discussion-between-feyre-and-junaid-aftab).

Answer (score 1):

For a given a, b, and t and changing gamma, we can see that the diference between the two functions stops changing for large values of gamma.

```
  f1[a_, b_, c_, t_] := 
     1/2 (1 + Sqrt[
         a^2 + (b Exp[-\[Gamma] (t)])^2 + (c Exp[-\[Gamma] (t)])^2])
    f2[a_, b_, c_, t_] := 1/2 (1 + a^2 + Exp[-\[Gamma] (t)] (b^2 + c^2))
    v = {10., 15., 7.}
    {a, b, c} = v/Norm[v]
    a^2 + b^2 + c^2
    Plot[{f1[a, b, c, 2.], f2[a, b, c, 2.]}, {\[Gamma], 0, 10}]
    Clear[a, b, c]
```

[image]

So assuming a big value to gamma, we obtain:

```
Simplify[f1[a, b, c, 1.] - f2[a, b, c, 1.]] /. \[Gamma] -> 
   100000 // Chop
```

-(a^2/2)

Comment: Yes, this is expected and all of my specific example show that this is the case. I'm interested in maximizing the difference in the region where the difference is changing.

Comment: @JunaidAftab Wouldn't that be just before they stop changing? Looking at the plot above the difference seems monotonically increasing

Comment: @user129412 Yes, you're right. Sorry for the mistake.